# Syntax for retrieving data from a List inside For loop in formula editor using Crystal Reports 8.5

Tags: crystal-reports, report

What is the syntax to retrieve data from a list inside a for loop in formula editor? I have written something like this but it is showing an error. Can anyone correct it?

```
Local NumberVar i;
Local NumberVar intCount := Count({FOODMASTER.FOOD_SORT});
For i := 1 to intCount Do
(
 If (i = 1) Then     
  {TMPMONTHLYDETAIL.TMP_QTY}[i];         
 Else If (i > 1) Then            
 Exit For;

 i := i + 1;

);
```

Where {FOODMASTER.FOOD_SORT} is of data type int and {TMPMONTHLYDETAIL.TMP_QTY} is decimal.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't really make a whole lot of sense logically, never mind the syntax. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You may need to rethink things a bit, but here are some things to get you started:

1. You don't need to manually increment `i` as the for-loop does it for you with a default step of 1.
2. You say {TMPMONTHLYDETAIL.TMP_QTY} is numeric, not an array or a string, so you cannot reference it via `{TMPMONTHLYDETAIL.TMP_QTY}[i]`.
3. Your for-loop doesn't actually do anything useful. At the start of the loop you do `i:=1` and then immediately check to see if `i=1`, otherwise you just exit the loop. The whole loop can be removed and reduced to just returning `{TMPMONTHLYDETAIL.TMP_QTY}[1]`.